# UML Class diagram - how do I represent different 'report' classes?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

If I am sitting down with a business stakeholder and creating a conceptual class diagram for the purpose of domain modelling, after asking the client what are all of the "things"  that the domain entails and he includes some comments along the lines of:

"We need 'Report 1' for abc and 'Report 2' for xyz and so on....."

How would I go about modelling these on the conceptual class diagram? Do I just represent reports the same as any other class/entity?  What if the client comes up with many different reports? Should reports be included on the conceptual class diagram at all?

Thanks

Comment: keep in my that instance vs. class confusion, modeling every report as a class seems incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should model the classes that will create or contain the information used in classes. IMHO Report looks like how they want to view it and should be modeled as part of GUI.